# Laravel 5.6 Auth Login page errors not showing blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am learning Laravel 5 and I have wrote following code for user login. I do not use sendFailedLoginResponse function in LoginController.php file. Now I am trying display validation errors messages with this code:

```
@if($errors->any())
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
           <ul>
               @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
      </div>
@endif
```

but nothing is displaying.

**routes.php**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('logout', function () {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect(route('dashboard'));
    });  
});
```

**login.blade.php form**

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="{{ url('login') }}" class="login-form">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group form-group-username">
        <label for="login-form-username">E-MAIL</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-mail adresinizi girin">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-password">
        <label for="login-form-password">ŞİFRE</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required="required" placeholder="Lütfen şifrenizi girin">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group form-group-button">
        <button type="submit" id="loginSend" class="button">Oturum Aç</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="login-form-reset-link">
        <a href="http://segments-demo.wearecodevision.com/reset-password/">Şifrenizi mi unuttunuz?</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-form-reset-link -->
</form>
```

**Kernel.php**

The Kernel.php file looks like this. Are you missing or too many lines?

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error->all() setting, wich view?

Comment: views/auth/login.blade.php

Comment: Can you try this only to now if flash alerts are working:
`@if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    @endif`

Comment: No, Not working

Comment: What actually do your app when try to login? Reload or what?

Comment: Is your Controller using `->withErrors()` anywhere? Probably beneficial to show your Controller logic regardless.

Comment: I want an error message after I reload the page. withErrors ()-> I do not use the  function anywhere.

Comment: After you reload the page? Reloading the page is triggering a `GET` request on the current URL. If you're not using `->withErrors()`, or `$request()->validate()`, etc etc, anywhere, `$errors->any()` is always going to be empty/false. Show your Controller logic.

Comment: I'm trying this way but not working,
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect('/')->with('flash_message_error', 'Test mesaj');
    }

Html;
@if(Session::has('flash_message_error'))
                <strong>{!! session('flash_message_error')!!}</strong>
            @endif

Comment: Try downloading laravel debugbar composer package.  This will give you the ability to review what is in your session, and should help you pinpoint where the issue is occuring.  For example, if the value you are expecting shows up in the "Session" tab for debugbar, then you know the ->with() method worked correctly, it's just not being displayed.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: @Dodiş are you sure your redirect comes from `sendFailedLogin...` and not from your middleware for example?

Comment: Hi friends, I'm added the kernel.php file. Look up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. After a lot of digging here and there, I solved it by removing *\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::clas*s from *$middlewareGroups* of *'web'* in app\http\kernel.php.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, // <-- Remove this
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```